# Why won't it sort my ICollection correctly using the instance method OrderByDescending?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have an `ICollection<Plante> Jardin` which I want to sort according to some property `Plante.Taille`:

```
private readonly ICollection<Plante> Jardin;
```

I use the instance method `OrderByDescending` :

```
public void TriDesc()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Tri par taille décroissante");

    IOrderedEnumerable<Plante> Temp = Jardin.OrderByDescending(a => a.Taille);
    Jardin.Clear();

    foreach (Plante p in Temp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.Taille);
        Jardin.Add(p);
    }
}
```

What is the problem here?

I tried debugging: `Temp` is correctly sorted by the method but `Jardin` is empty at the end.

Comment: `IOrderedEnumerable` is just a view of the list -- it doesn't copy the original data structure.  When you clear the list, there's no longer anything for `IOrderedEnumerable` to point to.  Just add to a new list.

Comment: Of course it is empty. _You explicitly `Clear()` it._

Comment: By any chance: is this meant to sort the list in-place?

Comment: Whaaaaat, I clear the list AFTER declaring the Temp List to store my <Plante> objects.

Comment: As remarked in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending), `OrderByDescending()` uses [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/classification-of-standard-query-operators-by-manner-of-execution#deferred).  So the sorting isn't actually done until you enumerate through `Temp`, at which point `Jardin` will have been cleared.

Comment: Since it seems you want to modify `Jardin`, you should sort it in place with [`List<T>.Sort()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-7.0).

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

As remarked in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending), `OrderByDescending()` is implemented using [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/classification-of-standard-query-operators-by-manner-of-execution#deferred):

> Deferred execution means that the operation is not performed at the point in the code where the query is declared. The operation is performed only when the query variable is enumerated, for example by using a `foreach` statement.

Thus the sorting isn't actually done until you enumerate through `Temp`, at which point `Jardin` will have been cleared:

```
// Define an ordering for `Jardin` but don't execute it yet.
IOrderedEnumerable<Plante> Temp = Jardin.OrderByDescending(a => a.Taille);

// Clear `Jardin`
Jardin.Clear();

// Execute and enumerate the ordering of `Jardin` (which is now empty):
foreach (Plante p in Temp)
{
    Jardin.Add(p);
}
```

Instead, you must materialize a copy of `Jardin` e.g. with [`ToList()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist) before clearing it and re-adding items items:

```
// Create an ordered copy of `Jardin`
var temp = Jardin.OrderByDescending(a => a.Taille).ToList();

// Clear `Jardin`
Jardin.Clear();

// Add the ordered items back:
foreach (var p in temp)
{
    Jardin.Add(p);
}
```

That being said, in C# [`ICollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1?view=net-7.0) is an interface that can be implemented by unordered collections such as `HashSet<T>` that do not necessarily preserve the order in which items are added.  If you need your `Jardin` collection to preserve order, consider using [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) instead:

```
private readonly List<Plante> Jardin;
```

If you do, it can be sorted in-place using [`List<T>.Sort()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-7.0#system-collections-generic-list-1-sort(system-comparison((-0)))):

```
// Sort Jardin in descending order of Taille
Jardin.Sort((x, y) => -x.Taille.CompareTo(y.Taille));
```

Notes:

- For a list of methods that use deferred execution, see [Classification of Standard Query Operators by Manner of Execution (C#): Classification Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/classification-of-standard-query-operators-by-manner-of-execution)
- [`OrderByDescending`](//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593386/why-wont-it-sort-my-icollection-correctly-using-the-instance-method-orderbydesc) is not an instance method, it is an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) in the [`System.Linq.Extensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=net-7.0) static class.